# Missing /etc/mysql folder

Tags: mysql, manjaro

I am trying to install mariadb and MySQL Workbench on Manjaro (my first time with this distro) and so far it has been a nightmare.

After a couple of days I've manage to install everything but I can not get to 'Options file' from Workbench. Checking at the instance settings it says that is a FreeBSD machine and when I change it to Linux it says that the config file is in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. However my system does not have that folder. My config file is directly in `/etc/my.cnf`

I've checked on my main machine (Pop!_OS 20.04) and it has indeed `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Also all the tutorials that I have found on internet points to he same path.

I am not sure if this is normal on this distro or I've messed up something during installation since I had to make use of a lot more commands for the installation on Manjaron than on Ubuntu.

Any idea?